# Deploy a vue.js app with IIS in sub directory without rebuilding

Tags: vue.js, iis

I want to deploy a vue.js app using IIS. We need to use subfolders and the same application will be present in different subfolders like

```
   /application-dev
   /application-qa
   /application-production
```

It is possible to set the path on build time using

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/application-dev'
}
```

But how can I set this at the time of deployment so that the application can be placed in any subfolder without rebuilding?

Answer (score 0):

i guess this can be a solution

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.PATH,
}
```

and for each environment you usa a different .env example:

- .env //local dev
- .env.dev //application-dev
- .env.qa //application-qa
- .env.prod //application-production

therefore for each release there will be a different environment with maybe a different CI for each branch connected to the environment

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: sub-directory
};
```

or according to NODE_ENV:

```
module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/production-sub-path/'
    : '/'
}
```

refer this below link for more detail:

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl